# Get last sql query for all open connections

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL 2008 R2, how can you query the database for all spids that are open and from that get the last sql query they made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic form is this using DMVs

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   sys.dm_exec_requests er
   CROSS APPLY
   sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) AS t
```

These can be refined or filtered as needed, for example like this link: https://sqlblog.org/2008/07/01/sys-dm_exec_requests